# How can I add value for Application Edition in manifest?

Tags: manifest, websphere-8

I'm looking for use WAS 8.5.5. Application Edition Management feature. I'd like to use the build to insert into manifest values for "Application Edition" and "Edition Descriptor" parameters, in order to be automatically valorized during ear installation. Do you know how can I named them?

For example, in order to valorize the Application Build ID I use "Implementation-Version" keyword.

Comment: The point of application editioning is to install the same application binary with multiple editions, so it wouldn't make sense to put the application edition in the binary.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I'd like to insert an identifier for the build, or the version of the ear itself. I manage to set this value with the build, automatically: I use an identifier that is currently the Implementation-Version that links all my scm-deploy pipeline using the same id. I'd like to use the same value also as edition identifier. Then, in order to automize the deployment (not the rollout itself) I'd like that this value could be automatically taken from manifest (as for the Implementation Version).

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  I'm not sure what I was thinking when I wrote my previous comment: obviously you want separate binaries for each edition since the whole point is to have different versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not specify edition no. anywhere in the EAR itself. But you can use the "wsInstalllApp" ant task to achieve automation:

```
<wsInstallApp ear="${server.home.dir}/${ear}" 
            options="-cell ${was.cell} -node ${was.node} -server ${was.server.to.deploy} -edition ${was.application.current.edition.number}" 
            failonerror="true" 
            conntype="${remote.connection.type}" 
            host="${remote.host.ip}" 
            port="${remote.connection.port}" 
            user="${remote.user.id}" 
            password="${remote.user.password}"
        />
```

You can find more information from [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twve_appedtop.html?lang=en) and [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rwve_adtaskapped.html?lang=en).